# Why before_save considered to be bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, activerecord, callback

I am sorry if similar question have been asked already I couldn't find anything identical.

Thus, can someone tell me why `before_save` especially conditional one can to be considered bad, please?

```
before_save :something, if: Proc.new { self.abc == 'hello' }
```

Therefore I understand why validation sometimes fits much better, however what I don't understand is why some people think that callbacks can to be a bad thing to use and they force you to write only validations but never make them conditional.

I personally think that there's can be far larger problem because this change can affect already existing entries and so it's okay to implement conditional validator or to provide `if` for `before_save` if you plan to modify data only in certain case. Why some people think it's not okay? Could someone help me with that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only disadvantage of `before_save` or `before_validation` is when it is not understood or used properly

- That it should be used only after carefully deliberating that such callbacks are really meant to be use global-wise for all records (consider also old records that are already stored in the DB)
- That if the callbacks are only applicable to certain specific records
  or conditions, then it is better to not pollute the model, and just implement the logic outside the model.
- That if the callbacks are changing a state, may it be the record or other records, then the names of those callbacks should be explicitly saying so, and that the developer should know and understood that these should not have inadvertent effects.
- That if the callbacks are not changing state, then it is immediately safe to use as it guarantees immutability and idempotence.
- That the order of the callbacks are important, and that limited understanding of what's happening may leave a developer / new developer to write code with inadvertent effects, and might not work all the time.
- That `before_save` and `before_validation` are different, and that a developer should understood that some callbacks are meant to be used as `before_save`, and some, as `before_validation`

Aside from these, I do not see any problem with `before_save` as it can potentially clean and break down the logic of the code, and allows reusability especially if you have subclasses of the model.

Just my immediate thoughts on the matter...

Answer (score 0):

Using callbacks are standard Rails practice! When used appropriately they are great DRY helpers when it comes to maintaining data-integrity.  Callbacks are heavily used for data-formatting user input (like removing spaces or dashes from a cellphone number field) where responding back with an error via a validation would just frustrate the user.  Use validations to handle cases you can't predict or data that would be otherwise unpredictable and callbacks elsewhere (like downcasing an email before saving).